# Loop in Visual Query (or other solution)

Tags: 2sxc

Hello 2sxc / SIC fans!

A little help would be appreciated on that ...

I use JavaScript Kendo UI components to display data in a grid. These data are transcribed in Json in order to benefit from the connection on the data source of a hierarchical grid.

On the one side, I have an "employees" table with their attributes `{ id, lastName, firstName, email }`. On the other hand, I have a list of training "events" `{ id, date, title, level }`.

So, I would like to add the date and title of the last training received into the attributes of each person. So I would like the output Json to be after processing `{ id, lastName, firstName, email, dateLastTraining, titleLastTraining }`.

One solution would be to re-manipulate the Json objects once I retrieve them in Razor but I would like to know if it was possible to do it directly at the source in the Visual Query.

I doubt this can be done because there should be a concept of loop (for each employee, filter the trainings according to the Id, sort them in order of date and take the Top1) and I think that there is no such possibility.

Am I wrong or would there be a solution to do that in Visual Query?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is a kind of join-operation. ATM (2sxc 9.14) this isn't possible in visual query.